Finding a Pivotal quantity
0
I am working on this problem for class, where the setup is the following:
Let X be a single observation from the beta(θ,1) pdf.
(b) Find a pivotal quantity and use it to set up a CI having the same confidence coefficient as the interval in part(a).
In part (a) I obtained e^{-1/2} - e^{-1} =.239.
The book we are using in class states that a good guess for a pivot would be $T=X^{\theta}$, and we should use it to set up the CI having the same conf. coeff. but I am failing to understand why it is a good pivot in this case.

Hint: What is the density of the distribution of $X$?

Ahh I see, now since the density of the distribution of X ~ Beta(\theta,1) -> \theta * X^{theta -1}. Using the properties scale and shape properties of the beta distribution it has been manipulated to make it free from theta. Thanks!
